# How to rename Animation Node's Invoke Subprogram;s Generator Output?

Tags: animation-nodes

I use a loop to modify the (1) points, (2) left handles, and (3) right handles of a spline. I then produce 3 Vector lists and use them to create a new spline. 
The following pictures shows how the x-coord of points are modified. The actual node tree has more complex logic for the points and handles.

There may be better way to I achieve the task. My question is not necessary about the best approach. The problem I have is that the 3 output lists are all named 'Vector List'. I have no way to tell which list is which when I am working them inside the Input Loop (because the actual layout of the nodes for manipulating the 3 Vector lists is not as neat as the attached picture). Is there a way to rename the 3 output lists so they can be descriptive. In this case I want them to match the input lists.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: You need to show a portion of your script to help people answer this. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to rename the Outputs of the **Invoke Subprogram** node and there are two ways to do that:

**Select the Output Node:**

1. Open the N-panel or properties panel --> Node --> Advanced Node Settings, there you can rename the output (blue box)
2. Or, press the U-key (which is a shortcut for the Output Node Settings), then a menu will appear in which you can rename the outputs (green box)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and picture!